# Asking for advice of how to appraoch an application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, listview

As part of a university project, I have to build an Android app that will contain informations about diseases, the diseases will be listed in a list (alphabetic order), when clicked on a disease you'll be directed to another layout that contains informations about the disease chosen (including text and images).

I don't know how to approach this app..and for the text should i build a database or directly input the text inside the app or something like that. If you know a tutorial or something that would help please share
Ps: there is almost 60 Diseases and each disease will have a subitems (causes, treatment, clinical signs .)

Comment: This is far too broad a question for SO. Take the [tour] and review [ask] to get a better idea of what's appropriate.

Comment: i just want guidline or tutorials, but i'm specialy concernd with the text , should i build a database or insert the text directly to android studio ..what do you think (i want the user to get access to the information without need for internet)

Comment: How you approach your solution would largely be dependent on the course goals. Is it just an exercise in UI design? Is there an emphasis on data and data structures? Have you covered database design? Beside being the wrong forum for this question, you have provided insufficient information to provide any help to you.

Comment: Did you consider asking the course professor?  When I was at University, I found most of the professors were quite approachable for questions, provided I hadn't slept through the lecture and missed it the first time around. ;)

Comment: i'm a veterinary student . not enrolled in a tech univ xD! that's why this challenging to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UI Design (List)

> there is almost 60 Diseases and each disease will have a subitems

Therefore I would suggest an `ExpandableListView`.
Check out this code sample:  https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial

Afterwards if the user clicks on an item, you open another `Activity` with details

### Data Storage

> should i build a database or directly input the text inside the app or
> something like that

#### Static approach

As you can think of, putting data directly into views makes it difficult to maintain, but is faster implemented and less difficult.

Implemenation: I would suggest putting the data into `res/raw` as a `.json` file. In your code, build a `JSONObject` out of it and pass it to the `ListViewAdapter`.

#### Dynamic approach

You need Internet permission, a webserver and a remote database from where you can query the data.

Implementation: If you have a hosted webserver you probably have `PHP` and `MySQL` databases. Create a `table`, fill it with data and build an API in `PHP` where you provide the data from the database. If you have a VPS or dedicated server you can use `MongoDB` which works with `JSON` out of the box.

### My guess

For an university project, use static. Otherwise dynamic of course.